# javascript in jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Hi I am trying to add some javascript in a jsp page but this is not working. below is my code.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".jsscript").fadeTo(20, 0.6);
    $(".jsscript").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(800, 0.6);
    });
    $(".jsscript").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(320, 1);
    });
})
</script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Gadgets</title>
</head>
```

This is the javascript used in my head tag and below is the image which is found on the same page

```
<td align="center"><img class="jsscript" src="images/<%=p.getFileName()%>" width="300"/></td>
```

Comment: Did you load jquery before the other script? E.g. Add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>` before the other script tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

add this to head

Comment: I suggest delete the question instead of posting an answer reiterating a comment

Comment: @mplungjan it's ok for OP to answer his own question: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: Of course it is, but a) the problem was a missing statement and b) the answer was just a copy of a comment

Answer (score -1):

Missing Semi column at last

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".jsscript").fadeTo(20, 0.6);
    $(".jsscript").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(800, 0.6);
    });
    $(".jsscript").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(320, 1);
    });
});
</script>
```

see your console.